# How to specify "ignore_patterns" here

Tags: python, shutil

Someone suggested using the following function to replace the original shutil.copytree function.

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

It worked fine except I wanted to pass some ignore_patterns to the variable 'ignore', my pattern is "*upf*", and it gives me following error.

```
    def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore= ignore_patterns('*upf*')):
NameError: name 'ignore_patterns' is not defined
```

Comment: ... well, the name `ignore_patterns` does not appear to be defined. Did you import it?

Comment: `from shutil import ignore_patterns`

Comment: That's right! I have imported ignore_patterns and the error has gone! Thank you! However my filter doesn't work as expected.  Under my source directory I have files with names "top.upf.0", "top.upf.1" ..."top.upf.5" that I wanted to be excluded when copying to the destination directory. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The [`ignore_patterns`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns) function belongs to the `shutil` module.

So, you can fix your code like below:

```py
import os
import shutil


def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("*upf")):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
```